# How to group a list of tuples/objects by similar index/attribute in python?

Tags: python, list, grouping

Given a list

```
old_list = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, ...]
```

I want to create a list:

```
new_list = [[obj_1, obj_2], [obj_3], ...]
```

where `obj_1.some_attr == obj_2.some_attr`.

I could throw some `for` loops and `if` checks together, but this is ugly. Is there a pythonic way for this? by the way, the attributes of the objects are all strings.

**Alternatively a solution for a list containing tuples (of the same length) instead of objects is appreciated, too.**

Comment: _" a list containing tuples (of the same length) instead of objects "_ Does this means **a list that contains tuples all of the same length** ? If yes, what is the "attribute" on which the tuples are grouped ? - BTW, tuples are objects, aren't they ?

Comment: @eyquem: 1. Yes; 2. the tuples are grouped at a certain index. The item at the index is a string.; 3. I believe so,... but I am not certain. :-)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

[`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is how this is done.

While `for` loops are largely essential, `if` statements aren't.

```
from collections import defaultdict


groups = defaultdict(list)

for obj in old_list:
    groups[obj.some_attr].append(obj)

new_list = groups.values()
```

Comment: This, of course, does not preserve (or respect in any way) the original order of groups. So it may or may not be what the @Druss wanted.

Comment: @jollybox.de: "does not preserve (or respect in any way) the original order of groups" Correct. When did that become a requirement?

Comment: I don't know whether it's a requirement, the original question isn't clear on that. I originally read the question that way. Still, good answer.

Comment: Just realized that if you combine the usage of a `dict` with the `itertools.groupby` answers, you don't even need to use `defaultdict`.

Comment: @jollybox.de: The ordering is not necessary. But thank you for forsight. :-) @S.Lott: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Should not one call `list(groups.values())` to actually return what OP wants? I mean, otherwise, if one calls `new_list[0]`, she gets `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing` (at leats on my machine).

Comment: Nice answer. How would one update this if instead we want to group the objects based on some threshold instead of exact equality?

Answer (score 40):

Here are two cases. Both require the following imports:

```
import itertools
import operator
```

You'll be using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and either [operator.attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) or [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

For a situation where you're grouping by `obj_1.some_attr == obj_2.some_attr`:

```
get_attr = operator.attrgetter('some_attr')
new_list = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(old_list, key=get_attr), get_attr)]
```

For `a[some_index] == b[some_index]`:

```
get_item = operator.itemgetter(some_index)
new_list = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(old_list, key=get_item), get_item)]
```

Note that you need the sorting because `itertools.groupby` makes a new group when the value of the key changes.

---

Note that you can use this to create a `dict` like S.Lott's answer, but don't have to use `collections.defaultdict`.

Using a dictionary comprehension (only works with Python 3+, and possibly Python 2.7 but I'm not sure):

```
groupdict = {k: g for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, keyfunction)}
```

For previous versions of Python, or as a more succinct alternative:

```
groupdict = dict(itertools.groupby(sorted_list, keyfunction))
```

Comment: `groupdict = {k: g for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, keyfunction)}` should be `groupdict = {k: list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, keyfunction)}` since `g` is just an interator.

Answer (score 16):

Think you can also try to use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby). Please note that code below is just a sample and should be modified according to your needs:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[3,2,3],[1,1,1],[7,8,9],[7,7,9]]

from itertools import groupby

# for example if you need to get data grouped by each third element you can use the following code
res = [list(v) for l,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[2]), lambda x: x[2])]# use third element for grouping
```

Comment: Basically my answer, but you forgot an important aspect: sorting before using `groupby`.

Comment: @JAB - your truth. Thank you for noticing me.

Comment: @JAB - Why sorting is required before using groupby ?

Comment: @SahilChhabra Read my answer, I say why.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I have also faced a similar issue. Thank you for the solutions provided above. I wrote a small comparison on the computation times of the above mentioned methods. In my implementation I keep the dictionary as it is nice to see the keys as well.
The method with `defaultdict` won.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import random


class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person(name='{self.name}', age={self.age})"


def method_with_dict(people):
    groups={}
    for person in people:
        if person.age in groups:
            groups[person.age].append(person)
        else:
            groups[person.age]=[person]
    return groups


def method_with_defaultdict(people):
    groups=defaultdict(list)
    for person in people:
        groups[person.age].append(person)
    return groups


def group_by_age_with_itertools(people):
    people.sort(key=lambda x: x.age)
    groups={}
    for age,group in itertools.groupby(people,key=lambda x: x.age):
        groups[age]=list(group)
    return groups


def group_by_age_with_pandas(people):
    df=pd.DataFrame([(p.name,p.age) for p in people],columns=["Name","Age"])
    groups=df.groupby("Age")["Name"].apply(list).to_dict()
    return {k: [Person(name,k) for name in v] for k,v in groups.items()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_people=1000
    min_age,max_age=18,80
    people=[Person(name=f"Person {i}",age=random.randint(min_age,max_age)) for i in
            range(num_people)]

    N=10000
    start_time=time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        result_defaultdict=method_with_defaultdict(people)
    end_time=time.time()
    print(f"method_with_defaultdict: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")


    start_time=time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        result_dict=method_with_dict(people)
    end_time=time.time()
    print(f"method_with_dict: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")

    start_time=time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        result_itertools=group_by_age_with_itertools(people)
    end_time=time.time()
    print(f"method_with_itertools: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")

    start_time=time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        result_pandas=group_by_age_with_pandas(people)
    end_time=time.time()
    print(f"method_with_pandas: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")


method_with_defaultdict: 0.954309 seconds
method_with_dict: 1.301710 seconds
method_with_itertools: 1.868009 seconds
method_with_pandas: 34.422366 seconds
```