# Why aren't Python dicts unified?

Tags: python

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602172/how-to-group-a-list-of-tuples-objects-by-similar-index-attribute-in-python), I noticed that S. Lott might have liked to use an “ordered defaultdict”, but it doesn't exist.  Now, I wonder: Why do we have so many dict classes in Python?

- dict
- blist.sorteddict
- collections.OrderedDict
- collections.defaultdict
- weakref.WeakKeyDictionary
- weakref.WeakValueDictionary
- others?

Why not have something like this,

```
dict(initializer=[], sorted=False, ordered=False, default=None, 
     weak_keys=False, weak_values=False)
```

that unifies everything, and provides every useful combination?

Comment: Then what happens when you use `a = {}`?

Comment: `{}` should default construct a regular dict?

Comment: I think he means, to get at the other forms of dict we use the `dict()` initialisation he described

Comment: I suppose that makes sense it's an interesting question

Comment: I like the idea, I wonder what would be the behaviour in cases where sorted=True and weak_keys=True

Comment: @Neil G: "S. Lott would have liked to use an “ordered defaultdict”.  Not really.  I saw no reason for considering order at all.

Comment: @Neil G: "Every Combination"?  Really?  Even future combinations that haven't been invented yet?

Comment: @S.Lott: I know you said you didn't consider it, but if it were part of the requirement, then your beautiful solution couldn't be used.  The `groupby` solution below yours is far uglier.

Comment: @fabrizioM: considering the restriction you mention and that sorted+ordered doesn't make sense, there are 20 possibilities (of which 6 are readily accessible today.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One issue is that making this change would break backward-compatibility, due to this type of constructor usage that exists now:

```
>>> dict(one=1, two=2)
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good reason. If having a single `dict` class was a good idea apart from backward compatibility, it would have been mooted for Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

Those extra options don't come for free. Since 99.9% of Python is built on `dict`, it is *very* important to make it as minimal and fast as possible.

Comment: Can't `__new__` be overridden so that the `dict` constructor returns the regular, lightweight `dict` class if all the other options are `False`/`None`?

Comment: How often are the other options likely to *not* be `False`/`None`?

Comment: The trouble is that with a problem like the linked problem, it's the combinations (like ordered defaultdict) you want that aren't available at all.  Also, I didn't know about all of these other dicts when I first started learning Python, and they would have been much more discoverable as options to the standard dict rather than tucked away in libraries that I had to find out about.

Answer (score 4):

Because the implementations differ a lot. You'd basically end up with a `dict` factory that returns an instance of a `_dict`(A very fast, low-overhead dictionary - the current `dict`), `ordereddict`, `defaultdict`, ... class. Also, you could not initialize dictionaries with keyword arguments anymore; programs relying on this would fail:

```
>>> dict(sorted=42)
{'sorted': 42}
# Your proposal would lead to an empty dictionary here (breaking compatibility)
```

Besides, when it's reasonable, the various classes already inherit from each other:

```
>>> collections.defaultdict.__bases__
(<type 'dict'>,)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why languages have "mixins".

You could try to invent something like the following by defining the right bunch of classes.

```
class defaultdict( dict, unordered, default_init ): pass
class OrderedDict( dict, ordered, nodefault_init ): pass
class WeakKeyDict( dict, ordered, nodefault_init, weakkey ): pass
class KeyValueDict( dict, ordered, nodefault_init, weakvalue ): pass
```

Then, once you have those "unified" dictionaries, your applications look like this

```
groups= defaultdict( list )
```

No real change to the app, is there?