# Grouping dictionary items by attribute

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to group the items in a dictionary by a particular key, let's say we have the following dictionary:

```
[{'type': 'animal', 'name': 'rabbit'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'cow'}, {'type': 'plant', 'name': 'orange tree'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'coyote'}]
```

And I wanted to group these items by `type`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602172/how-to-group-a-list-of-tuples-objects-by-similar-index-attribute-in-python) this can be done using `defaultdict()` because it doesn't raise a `KeyError`, as follows:

```
grouped = defaultdict()
for item in items:
    grouped[item.type].append(item)
```

However, I am actually getting a `KeyError`.

So what's wrong? All the information I see says `defaultdict()` is supposed to create an empty list if it's not existing, and the insert the element.

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `defaultdict(list)`, not `defaultdict()`. Read the docs for defaultdict to find out more.

Also, you cannot use some_dict.a_key (in your case: .type) - you must use some_dict['a_key'] (in your case ['type'])

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a normal dictionary and its [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
l = [{'type': 'animal', 'name': 'rabbit'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'cow'}, {'type': 'plant', 'name': 'orange tree'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'coyote'}]
d = {}
for x in l:
    d.setdefault(x["type"], []).append(x)
print d
```

The result would be this (nicely formatted):

```
{'plant' : [{'type': 'plant', 'name': 'orange tree'}], 
 'animal': [{'type': 'animal', 'name': 'rabbit'}, 
            {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'cow'}, 
            {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'coyote'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

animals=[{'type': 'animal', 'name': 'rabbit'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'cow'}, 
{'type': 'plant', 'name': 'orange tree'}, {'type': 'animal', 'name': 'coyote'}]

animal_by_type = defaultdict(list)
for animal in animals:
    animal_by_type[animal['type']].append(animal['name'])
print animal_by_type
```