# How to group objects (tuples) based on having consecutive attribute value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping

I found a similar question here:
[How to group a list of tuples/objects by similar index/attribute in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602172/how-to-group-a-list-of-tuples-objects-by-similar-index-attribute-in-python#)
which talks about grouping a list of tuples by similar attributes. I have a list of objects; the objects have a 'day' attribute and I want to group these objects based on if they have consecutive 'day' values.
e.g

```
input = [('a',12),('b',13)('c',15),('d',16),('e',17)]
```

output:

```
[[('a',12),('b',13)],[('c',15),('d',16),('e',17)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from operator import itemgetter

data = [('a', 12), ('b', 13), ('c', 15), ('c', 16), ('c', 17)]


def key(i, cursor=count(0)):
    """Generate the same key for consecutive numbers"""
    return i[1] - next(cursor)


ordered = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))

result = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(ordered, key=key)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[('a', 12), ('b', 13)], [('c', 15), ('c', 16), ('c', 17)]]
```

The above is based on an old example found in the documentation of Python 2.6, [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples).

To better illustrate, what is happening, for the following example:

```
lst = [12, 13, 15, 16, 17]
print([v - i for i, v in enumerate(lst)])
```

The generated keys are:

```
[12, 12, 13, 13, 13]
```

As it can be seen, consecutive runs have the same key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I apply it to my code it throws the following error:


TypeError: 'NameOfObject' object does not support indexing

Comment: Hi, that must be because NameOfObject is not a tuple, as in your example. Instead using itemgetter, use attrgetter