# Assigning elements of a list to correct list

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns

I have a list of `chunk` objects that I would like to iterate through and sort into lists where all `chunk` elements have the same name.
I wrote this:

```
zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

for chunk in self.chunk_collection:
    if chunk.chunk_name == "0":
       zero.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "1":
       one.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "2":
       two.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "3":
       three.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "4":
       four.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "5":
       five.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "6":
       six.append(chunk)
    if chunk.chunk_name == "7":
       seven.appned(chunk)
```

Which allows me to iterate through the `chunk_collection` once, but this doesn't scale well at all.

What if there are `n` lists I would like to sort the contents of `chunk_collection` into!

Is there a better way to write this code or is there a pattern that I should implement so I don't have to come across this problem at all?

Comment: Yep - try the approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602172/how-to-group-a-list-of-tuples-objects-by-similar-index-attribute-in-python .

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks it was hard putting the question into words to search.